# Task Board does not show WorkItems that have the State "In Progress"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

We have a problem with our TFS 2013.

We are trying to set up our Taskboard. Unfortunately, the taskboard is only showing workitems with the state `New`, `Committed`, and `Done`. But workitems with the state `In Progress` aren't showing up.

Does anybody know a solution for this? Do I have to add the state `In Progress` somewhere in the process template?

Our process template is „Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.4" and we customized a few things in it.

Here's a screenshot of what I meant to describe:

[image: PBIs invisible]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no default "In Progress" state of the workitems created in backlog. Seems you have customize it and add this state.

If you want this workitem with "In Progress" state also shown in the task. You should also customize your backlog

```
<RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Backlog items" singularName="Backlog item">
   <States>
      <State value="New" type="Proposed" />
      <State value="Approved" type="Proposed" />
      <State value="Committed" type="InProgress" />
      <State value="Done" type="Complete" />
   </States>
 . . .
</RequirementBacklog >
```

Then add  a value such as below:

```
 <State value="In Progress" type="InProgress" />
```

You may need some restart after the changing, more details please refer this link: [Map WIT category workflow states to metastates](https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/work/reference/process-configuration-xml-element#map-wit-category-workflow-states-to-metastates)

Comment: Hello, sry that I've mislead you. In this specific case I am talking about userstories and not the tasks. Tasks are shown as they should.

Comment: Could you add a related screenshot for this ?

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, I think I got what you mean. Please go through my update answer to see if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I think you've got me correct this time. Yes, its very likely we added a custom state to the Product Backlog Items, I can't tell you for sure, cause I have not been in this team from the beginning. How do I retrieve and update my current RequirementBacklog XML? Over the WIT command line tool?

Comment: Sorry for  later reply. To update the process configuration for a team project, you should export the XML definition file, edit it, and then import the file. You export these files either by [exporting a process](https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/work/import-process/import-process#export-a-process) or [exporting the process configuration definition file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh500413.aspx). You could also install  [TFS Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) Note:match  VS version